# How to work around NAs introduced by coercion in R?

Tags: r, stringr

```
participated in the review for their constructive contributions, and to the international organizations. He urged them to continue to show solidarity with C™te dÕIvoire. In closing, he said that, more than ever, C™te dÕIvoire needed their support in order to attain its objectives ahead of 2020. 

*II. Conclusions and/or recommendations*
127. The recommendations listed below enjoy the support of C™te dÕIvoire: 
127.1 Consider the accession to core human rights instruments (Lesotho); and to other main international human rights treaties that it is not yet a party to (Philippines); 
127.2 Make efforts towards the ratification of the OP-CAT (Chile); 
127.3 Ratify the OP-CAT (Ghana, Tunisia), as recommended previously in 2009 (Czech Republic) and take policy measures to prevent torture and ill-treatment (Estonia);
```

This is my text, and I want to extract everything after, *II. Conclusions and/or recommendations*
I have tried the following;

```
x <- substring(text, first = "II. Conclusions and/or recommendations\n")
```

But Im getting the NAs introduced by coercion. what do I do to make it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text <- "participated in the review for their constructive contributions, and to the international organizations. He urged them to continue to show solidarity with C™te dÕIvoire. In closing, he said that, more than ever, C™te dÕIvoire needed their support in order to attain its objectives ahead of 2020. 

*II. Conclusions and/or recommendations*
127. The recommendations listed below enjoy the support of C™te dÕIvoire: 
127.1 Consider the accession to core human rights instruments (Lesotho); and to other main international human rights treaties that it is not yet a party to (Philippines); 
127.2 Make efforts towards the ratification of the OP-CAT (Chile); 
127.3 Ratify the OP-CAT (Ghana, Tunisia), as recommended previously in 2009 (Czech Republic) and take policy measures to prevent torture and ill-treatment (Estonia);"
```

Use this:

```
substring(text, regexpr("II.", text))
```

Or by giving start position as an integer:

```
substring(text, 300)
```